# Steam problems on Void Linux

Tags: linux, steam, void-linux

I have recently installed Void Linux. After a recent system update, Steam no longer works. My NVIDIA drivers are loaded and working, and the flatpak version of Steam works fine. Heres a log of what happens when I run steam:

```
$ steam
/home/ethan/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 117: VERSION_ID: unbound variable
/home/ethan/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 117: VERSION_ID: unbound variable
Running Steam on void  64-bit
/home/ethan/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 117: VERSION_ID: unbound variable
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
Can't find 'steam-runtime-check-requirements', continuing anyway
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/ethan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2021-11-12 19:44:17] Startup - updater built Oct 13 2021 19:47:06
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
^C
```

I've tried deleting `~/.steam` and `~/.local/share/Steam` and disabling the Steam runtime. I also have followed the directions in `/usr/share/doc/steam/README.voidlinux` Any Ideas?

Comment: @jsotola does that result in a page for you with instructions that the OP hasn't tried? If so, is there an Answer there, or a need for more clarification from the OP?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late response, @jsotola I had googled that error and found that most people who had that error it was completely unrelated to my problem. Steam still worked before and the VERSION_ID error was there, so that is not the issue.